# Images and text not aligning properly

Tags: html, css

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSAxH/1/)

I have created above jsFiddle, as you can see, as soon as I add the images in, everything is a chaos. When I don't add the images, they align perfectly well.
How can I fix this?

```
<section class="buttons">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="fotografie.html"><span><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" /></span><span>Fotografie</span><span><img src="http://placehold.it/16x25" /></span></a><hr /></li>
        <li><a href="360.html"><span><img src="img/Icon-360.png" /></span><span>360&deg; Foto&apos;s</span><span><img src="img/Pijltje.png" /></span></a><hr /></li>
        <li><a href="plattegrond.html"><span><img src="img/Icon-plattegrond.png" /></span><span>Plattegronden</span><span><img src="img/Pijltje.png" /></span></a><hr /></li>
        <li><a href="video.html"><span><img src="img/Icon-video.png" /></span><span>Artist Impressions</span><span><img src="img/Pijltje.png" /></span></a><hr /></li>
        <li><a href="artist_impression.html"><span><img src="img/Icon-Artist-Impression.png" /></span><span>Video</span><span><img src="img/Pijltje.png" /></span></a><hr /></li>
        <li><a href="inmeten.html"><span><img src="img/Icon-Inmeten.png" /></span><span>Inmeten</span><span><img src="img/Pijltje.png" /></span></a><hr /></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

With following styles:

```
.buttons{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.buttons ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.buttons ul li{
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(214, 55, 45);
    border-bottom: 1px white;
}
.buttons ul li a{
    color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    display: block;
}
.buttons ul li a span{
    color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.buttons ul li a span img{
    line-height: 60px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.buttons ul li a span:nth-child(2){
    padding-left: 100px;
}
.buttons ul li a span:last-child{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: What is your expected result? What is 'proper' alignment?

Comment: Your 60x60 image is causing chaos! [See](http://jsfiddle.net/CSAxH/2/)

Comment: @oGeez: Proper alignment is vertically alignment of the images and the text, I want them all vertically centered.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak: I did see that, I don't know how to solve that, though. Because it is disturbing everything.

Comment: The images in the Fiddle are dead links. If they don't load we can't see how they render.

Comment: @doctororange: In my jsFiddle link, I have put placehold.its, because of the size my icon's and images are, it was easier to do it this way.

Comment: You seem to have used placehold.its for only one of the images. Are they all 60x60, or are they different dimensions? This will affect the potential solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have updated your code. Please check the link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/binita07/CSAxH/3/

```
.buttons{
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.buttons ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.buttons ul li{
display: block;
height: 70px;
background-color: rgb(214, 55, 45);
border-bottom: 1px white;
}
.buttons ul li a{
color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 70px;
font-size: 1.25em;
display: block;
}
.buttons ul li a span{
color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.25em;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.buttons ul li a span img{
line-height: 70px;
padding-left: 50px;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.buttons ul li a span:nth-child(2){
padding-left: 100px;
}
.buttons ul li a span:last-child{
float: right;
position: relative;
right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, it was so simple, after all, thank you very much, Binita!